# I want to optimize my solution using memoization. Can someone help me?

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

By starting with an empty string, we can perform either of the following:

- Append the character '0' `zero` times.
- Append the character '1' `one` times.

Given low and high as the minimum and maximum length of the string, find out the total number of strings that can be formed.

Example:
Input: low = 2, high = 3, zero = 1, one = 2
Output: 5

The strings are "00", "11", "000", "110", and "011".

```
int count = 0;
public int count(int low, int high, String s, String a, String b) {
        int len = s.length();
        if(len > high){
            return 0;
        }
        if(len >= low){
            count++;
        }
        // System.out.println(s);

        int left = count(low, high, s + a, a, b);
        int right = count(low, high, s + b, a, b);

        return count;
    }

    public int countGoodStrings(int low, int high, int zero, int one) {
        String a = "0";
        String b = "1";
        a = a.repeat(zero);
        b = b.repeat(one);
        int[] dp = new int[high + 1];
        Arrays.fill(dp, -1);
        // System.out.print(b);
        int ans = counttop(low, high, "", a, b);
    }
```

This will give a TLE as it takes exponential time. Can someone demonstrate how to use memoization here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't compute the strings, just count them. To do it fast, you need to memoize the number of possible strings for any given string size. In Python,

```
def count(low, high, zeros, ones):
  def count_k(k):
    if k<0:
      return 0
    if k not in cache:
      cache[k] = count_k(k-zeros) + count_k(k-ones)
    return cache[k]

  cache = {0:1}
  return sum(count_k(k) for k in range(low, high+1))
```